# EMF: How to create model instance programmatically without using eclipse instance

Tags: serialization, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-emf

With EMF I can import an ecore file (metamodel), generate the code then debug the project as a new eclipse instance to play with my model instance. My purpose is to create my instance without loading a new eclipse instance, for example I would like to create a new Java project that use my generated code to create the instance assuming that I'll do some validation/OCL to have an instance that I can serialize to an XMI file.

I was thinking about export the generated code (Model, Edit, Editor) to a JAR file or as a plugin, but it didn't work perfectly. Do you have any suggestion or HowTo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by "without loading a new eclipse instance", but if you want to get rid of the EMF and Eclipse-dependencies you can achieve this by editing your genmodel. This recipe explains the steps in detail: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EMF/Recipes#Recipe:_Generating_Pure_API_With_No_Visible_EMF_Dependencies

Not everything EMF has to offer will work with this solution, but it might be sufficient for what you want.

Comment: This not exactly what I want, as you know if I want to instantiate my model I have to "run" a new instance of eclipse, import my model then instantiate using EMF Tool, I want to do this without opening a new eclipse runtime environment

Comment: Well, if you get rid of the Eclipse dependencies you do not have to run a new instance of eclipse. This will definitely work for the model, probably for edit, but as fas as I know not for the editor.
If you want to use the generated editor you will need to run a new eclipse instance, otherwise you don't. Of course you will have to follow the recipe above and configure your launch-configuration accordingly.